# Java 11 Swing Issue in MetalLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, java-11

We are moving to Java 11 and in the course have to modify few of the
legacy code. The front end of our application is basically in Swing. I
am not very use to it, so need some help/input.

In our old code we have customize our `LookAndFeel` API by directly
extending to Java internal API `WindowsLookAndFeel`. I tried to resolve
it by adding the below lines in build script:

```
-add-exports java.desktop/com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows=ALL-UNNAMED
```

But there are several issues which we encounter during running it
related to UI.

In order to completely resolve it for future release we are planning to
use `MetalLookAndFeel` API. It is working perfectly fine but the only
issue which I am facing is related to refresh.

The action is not getting reflected immediately. Let's say I click some
of the tab then in order to see it, I have to minimize/click other
tab.

Just wanted to know  if I am missing anything.

```
package com.osm.ui.laf.ctc;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

import com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel;



public class PtcLaf extends MetalLookAndFeel {
    private final String ctcPackageName = "com.osm.ui.laf.ctc."; //frozen
    private Boolean useCTCWindowDecoration = null;

    @Override
    public boolean getSupportsWindowDecorations() {
        if (useCTCWindowDecoration == null) {
            final String val = System.getProperty("use.ctc.window.decoration"); //frozen

            if (val != null) {
                useCTCWindowDecoration = val.equals("true"); //frozen
            } else {
                useCTCWindowDecoration = true;
            }
        }

        return useCTCWindowDecoration.booleanValue();
    }

    @Override
    protected void initClassDefaults(UIDefaults table) {
        super.initClassDefaults(table);

        final Object[] defaults = {
                "RootPaneUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRootPaneUI", //frozen
                "MenuItemUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcMenuItemUI", //frozen
                "SeparatorUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcSeparatorUI", //frozen
                "PopupMenuSeparatorUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcSeparatorUI", //frozen
                "RadioButtonMenuItemUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRadioButtonMenuItemUI", //frozen
                "CheckBoxMenuItemUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcCheckBoxMenuItemUI", //frozen
                "MenuUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcMenuUI", //frozen
                "RibbonApplicationMenuButtonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonApplicationMenuButtonUI", //frozen
                "RibbonApplicationMenuPopupPanelUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonApplicationMenuPopupPanelUI", //frozen
                "RibbonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonUI", //frozen
                "RibbonGalleryUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonGalleryUI", //frozen
                "RibbonBandUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonBandUI", //frozen
                "RibbonTaskToggleButtonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonTaskToggleButtonUI", //frozen
                "CommandButtonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcCommandButtonUI", //frozen
                "EmptyCommandButtonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcEmptyCommandButtonUI", //frozen
                "CommandButtonPanelUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcCommandButtonPanelUI", //frozen
                "CommandMenuButtonUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcCommandMenuButtonUI", //frozen
                "CommandPopupMenuUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcCommandPopupMenuUI", //frozen
                "ScrollablePanelUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcScrollablePanelUI", //frozen
                "TabbedPaneUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcTabbedPaneUI", //frozen
                "RichTooltipPanelUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcRichTooltipPanelUI", //frozen
                "ComboBoxUI", ctcPackageName + "PtcComboBoxUI" //frozen

            };

        table.putDefaults(defaults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initComponentDefaults(final UIDefaults table) {
        super.initComponentDefaults(table);

        initResourceBundle(table);

        // Initalise all the defaults.  
        final Object[] defaults = {
                "activeCaption", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "inactiveCaption", new ColorUIResource(200, 200, 200), //frozen
                "activeCaptionText", new ColorUIResource(58, 58, 58), //frozen
                "inactiveCaptionText", new ColorUIResource(138, 138, 138), //frozen
                                                                           // Active window colors
                "InternalFrame.activeTitleBackground", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.activeTitleGradient", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.activeTitleForeground", new ColorUIResource(58, 58, 58), //frozen
                                                                                        // Inactive window colors
                "InternalFrame.inactiveTitleBackground", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.inactiveTitleGradient", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.inactiveTitleForeground", new ColorUIResource(207, 207, 207), //frozen
                                                                                             // Icons for frames
                "InternalFrame.maximizeIcon", LookAndFeel.makeIcon(this.getClass(), "icons/maximize_12x12.png"), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.closeIcon", LookAndFeel.makeIcon(this.getClass(), "icons/close_12x12.png"), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.minimizeIcon", LookAndFeel.makeIcon(this.getClass(), "icons/restore_12x12.png"), //frozen
                "InternalFrame.iconifyIcon", LookAndFeel.makeIcon(this.getClass(), "icons/minimize_12x12.png"), //frozen
                                                                                                                // Window borders
                "RootPane.frameBorder.radius", 11, //frozen
                "RootPane.frameBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.plainDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.informationDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.errorDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.colorChooserDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.fileChooserDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.questionDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "RootPane.warningDialogBorder", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcFrameBorder"), //frozen
                                                                                                     // Menu
                "MenuItem.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(246, 220, 150), //frozen
                "MenuItem.selectionBackgroundGradient", new ColorUIResource(251, 238, 203), //frozen
                "MenuItem.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
                "MenuItem.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 255, 255), //frozen
                "MenuItem.foreground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
                "MenuItem.disabledForeground", new ColorUIResource(200, 200, 200), //frozen
                "MenuItem.lineColor", new ColorUIResource(200, 200, 200), //frozen
                "Menu.submenuPopupOffsetX", new Integer(0), //frozen
                "Menu.submenuPopupOffsetY", new Integer(-1), //frozen
                "PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray), //frozen
                "MenuBar.background", new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                "MenuItem.borderColor", Color.gray, //new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                                                    // Toolbar
                "ToolBar.background", new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                "Toolbar.darkColor", new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                "Toolbar.lightColor", Color.white, //new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                "WindowsToolBar.underline", Color.gray, //frozen
                                                        // Task bars
                "Taskbar.head.text.plain", Color.black, //frozen
                "Taskbar.head.text.selected", new ColorUIResource(25, 25, 25), //frozen
                "Taskbar.head.bar.left", new ColorUIResource(206, 210, 213), //frozen
                "Taskbar.head.bar.right", new ColorUIResource(206, 210, 213), //frozen
                "Taskbar.item.background", new ColorUIResource(226, 230, 233), //frozen
                "SplashScreen.border", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcSplashScreenFrameBorder"), //frozen
                "SplashScreen.border.radius", 11, //frozen
                                                  //Ribbon
                "RibbonBand.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "RibbonBand.title.background", new ColorUIResource(238, 240, 241), //frozen
                "RibbonBand.title.borderline", new ColorUIResource(199, 202, 204), //frozen
                "RibbonBand.border", new PtcLazyValue(ctcPackageName + "PtcRibbonBandBorder"), //frozen
                "ControlPanel.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "RibbonUI.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                "RibbonApplicationMenuButton.background", new ColorUIResource(238, 240, 241), //frozen
                "RibbonApplicationMenuButton.foreground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
                "RibbonApplicationMenuButton.border.color", new ColorUIResource(199, 202, 204), //frozen
                "Ribbon.border", BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(), //frozen
                "BandHostPanel.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
                                                                                // Table selection colors
                "Table.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
                "Table.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(246, 220, 150), //frozen
                                                                                 //Combo box list Colors
                "ComboBox.List.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(0, 0, 0), //frozen
                "ComboBox.List.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(246, 220, 150), //frozen
                                                                                         // Tabbed pane colors
                "TabbedPane.tabSelectedBackground", new ColorUIResource(246, 220, 150), //frozen
                "TabbedPane.tabSelectedBackgroundGradient", new ColorUIResource(251, 238, 203), //frozen
                "TabbedPane.borderColor", new ColorUIResource(145, 145, 145), //frozen
                "TabbedPane.tabBackground", new ColorUIResource(220, 220, 220), //frozen
                "TabbedPane.tabBackgroundGradient", new ColorUIResource(240, 240, 240), //frozen
                "QuickSearchField.border.color", new ColorUIResource(199, 202, 204), //frozen
                "StatusPanel.background", new ColorUIResource(251, 251, 251), //frozen
            };
        table.putDefaults(defaults);
    }

    private void initResourceBundle(UIDefaults table) {
        table.addResourceBundle("com.sun.swing.internal.plaf.metal.resources.metal"); //frozen
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CTC Look And Feel"; //frozen
    }

    @Override
    public String getID() {
        return "CTCLAF"; //frozen
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "CTC Look And Feel"; //frozen
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNativeLookAndFeel() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSupportedLookAndFeel() {
        return true;
    }
}

package com.osm.ui.laf;

import java.awt.Window;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import com.osm.datamgmt.ui.WindowManager;
import com.osm.ui.laf.ctc.PtcLaf;
import com.osm.ui.laf.xplookandfeel.XPLookAndFeel;


public class LookAndFeelManager {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LookAndFeelManager.class.getName());
    private static LookAndFeelManager instance;
    final List<LookAndFeelDescriptor> availableLAFs;
    private LookAndFeelDescriptor currentLAF;

    private LookAndFeelManager() {
        // if we wanted to expose all installed LAFs, we'd do something like
        /*
        UIManager.installLookAndFeel("Windows XP", XPLookAndFeel.class.getName()); //frozen
        UIManager.installLookAndFeel("Office 2010", PtcLaf.class.getName()); //frozen
        final LookAndFeelInfo[] lafs = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
         */
        availableLAFs = new ArrayList<LookAndFeelDescriptor>();
        availableLAFs.add(new LookAndFeelDescriptor("Windows XP", XPLookAndFeel.class.getName())); //frozen
        availableLAFs.add(new LookAndFeelDescriptor("PTC", PtcLaf.class.getName())); //frozen

        currentLAF = findCurrentLAFDescriptor();
    }

    public static synchronized LookAndFeelManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new LookAndFeelManager();
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public static synchronized void clearInstance() {
        instance = null;
    }

    public List<LookAndFeelDescriptor> getAvailableLookAndFeels() {
        return availableLAFs;
    }

    public LookAndFeelDescriptor getCurrentLookAndFeel() {
        return currentLAF;
    }

    public void setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeelDescriptor lafDescriptor) {
        if (lafDescriptor == null) {
            log.warning("LAF is null"); //frozen

            return;
        }

        if (lafDescriptor.equals(currentLAF)) {
            return;
        }

        log.info("Setting LAF " + lafDescriptor); //frozen

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lafDescriptor.getClassName());
            currentLAF = lafDescriptor;

            final Collection<Window> frames = WindowManager.getInstance().getFrames();

            for (Window frame : frames) {
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not set LAF", e); //frozen
        }
    }

    private LookAndFeelDescriptor findCurrentLAFDescriptor() {
        final LookAndFeel laf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
        final String lafClassName = laf.getClass().getName();

        for (LookAndFeelDescriptor descriptor : availableLAFs) {
            if (lafClassName.equals(descriptor.getClassName())) {
                return descriptor;
            }
        }

        log.warning("No LAF descriptor found"); //frozen

        return null;
    }

    // Quite similar to UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo but with a more readable 'toString()'
    public static class LookAndFeelDescriptor {
        private String name;
        private String className;

        public LookAndFeelDescriptor(String name, String className) {
            this.name = name;
            this.className = className;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return className;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }

            if (!(obj instanceof LookAndFeelDescriptor)) {
                return false;
            }

            return className.equals(((LookAndFeelDescriptor) obj).getClassName());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = (prime * result) + ((className == null) ? 0 : className.hashCode());
            result = (prime * result) + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);` after setting a new PLAF, where `frame` is the top level container of the components.

Comment: I can already see your suggestion in the code. Kindly look now , I have updated.

Comment: Let me know when you've posted an MCVE / SSCCE & I'll look more closely at it.